# Percentage complete cell based upon highlighted cells in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Beginning of the table I created.]

I have a table that I want to get a percentage from but I want it to be a rolling percentage so that when I highlight a cell the percentage changes. There's no values in the cells that I want to highlight, but the percentage should change when I highlight said cell.

Comment: sounds like you'll need VBA to do what you want. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is acceptable for you or not but I created a sample that is loosely based upon your given parameters, only rather than highlighting cells I used a slider control instead.  I've hosted the sample file [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b7vtnoztrCbQGArmPy-kocYE1O-pAwQc); here's a screenshot:

(
[image]